# Tutorials on cron

Tags: cron

Kindly tell me where to find excellent tutorials on cron. I have searched google for this. But most sites give tutorials which are not complete. I dont need links to those tutorials which are incomplete and shabby.

Comment: Not strictly what you were looking for but checkout this cron generator. http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [All about Cron on one page](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/time.html#cron)

An excellent, and very thorough tutorial.  Covers all aspects of cron, from background to practical examples.  If it's not on this page, it's not worth knowing.

also covers similar/related tools `anacron`, `at` and `batch`, as well as the general concepts of time in Unix.

Comment: Thanks Colin, Superb tutorials..As you said "If it's not on this page, it's not worth knowing"

Answer (score 1):

I have never found a truly comprehensive cron tutorial, to be comprehensive it needs to explain crontab lines like:

```
2-57/5 *   *  *  * $COMMAND
```

I have not seen one that does so properly.

http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui is a somewhat useful web utility for building crontabs. It does not explain the concepts but lets you build a crontab line by selecting the times you want without having to remember the syntax. Unfortunately it fails at more complex examples but is nonetheless a useful tool.

http://cronwtf.github.com/ is a somewhat useful web utility for parsing crontab lines and giving an english explanation of when the command will run. It does not deal properly with my example above.