# recurrently copy a file from one directory to another after every 30 minutes or 1 hour automatically

Tags: php

How can I automatically copy files from a source directory to the destination directory after some time say like after every 30 minutes?

Comment: are you trying to do this client side?  server side? what are you doing? and what have you tried?

Comment: This cannot be done with javascript or jQuery.

Comment: this is usualy done using [cron jobs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275607/tutorials-on-cron

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP (or JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

If your using a standerd LAMP stack you could just make a cron job that calls rsync.

eg run crontab -e

and add an entry such as

```
* * * * * rsync -av /path/to/files/source/ /path/to/copy/files/to/
```

will copy the files ever 1 min.

check out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync