# Is this possible to automate the JMeter scripts running schedule?

Tags: jmeter

Is this possible to schedule the JMeter scripts.for example I want to run the same script every hour and want to automate this process.Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks UBIK LOAD PACK!! Answer is useful for me. but somehow I'm unable to upvote it.I'm new here and 'Vote up requires 15 reputations'.But I just scheduled the task through the windows task scheduler and found it pretty easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many options:

- Linux : Use [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275607/tutorials-on-cron)
- [Windows Task Scheduler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308569)
- [Jenkins](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-maven-jenkins/)